# Me da un error en c++ cuando quiero utilizar un método el cual imprima un mensaje

Tags: c++, poo, clase, método, impresión

¿Alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer que un método pueda imprimir un mensaje con parametros? Puse el using namespace std; y el #include en Punto.cpp, pero me marca error en la parte de cout, a pesar que invoco el namespace std y el #include

Imprimiendo el código lo único que me marca error es en el cout en main.cpp, y es porque dice que no está definido, ¿acaso se necesita utilizar otra librería para ello? ¿o se debe de escribir de una determinada forma?

Me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación les muestro mi código:

```
//Punto.h 

#ifndef PUNTO_H_
#define PUNTO_H_

class Punto{
  private:
    int punto1, punto2;

  public:
    Punto(int p1, int p2);

    ~Punto();

    int getPunto1();

    int getPunto2();

    void GenerarSuma();
};

//----------------------------------------------------------

//Punto.cpp

#include "Punto.h"
#include <string>
#include "iostream" 
using namespace std; 

Punto::Punto(int p1, int p2){
  punto1 = p1;
  punto2 = p2;

}

Punto::~Punto(){

}
//Método para imprimir
void GenerarSuma(){
  cout<<"los puntos son: ";
  }

int Punto::getPunto1(){
  return punto1;
}

int Punto::getPunto2(){
  return punto2;
}

----------------------------

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Punto.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int p1, p2;

  Punto puntito(1,2);



  cout<<"Sus puntos x,y son respectivamente: "<<puntito.getPunto1()<<","<<puntito.getPunto2()<<endl;


  //AQUÍ ES DONDE ME DICE QUE PROVIENE EL ERROR SEGÚN LA CONSOLA.
  puntito.GenerarSuma(); 


  




  return 0;
}

*
```

Lo extraño es que cuando quito ese puntito.GenerarSuma(); el programa si me corre con total normalidad, ¿alguien me podría explicar cómo se debe de programar de tal manera que se pueda utilizar el método para imprimir un mensaje?
Gracias por leerme <3

Comment: Por favor, el código y otros datos relevantes, como los errores, se han de colocar **en texto**. Las imágenes no se pueden copiar/pegar para hacer pruebas ni realizar búsquedas, y hacen mas difícil que nadie pueda ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Que pena, soy nueva

Comment: Solo tienes que [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/386124/edit) tu pregunta y arreglarla.

Comment: Gracias por el pequeño tutorial :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion GenerarSuma() no pertenece a la clase Punto, olvidaste poner el operador de  resolución de ámbito que son los "::"

```
void  Punto::GenerarSuma(){
      //codigo
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Había pasado ese pequeño detalle